# How to auto change font size by text length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making buttons and have a little problem with text. I want all texts on buttons made the same width. My code:

```
<span class="text">SVDFBDFBSFG</span>
<br />
<span class="text">FHEWFG</span>
<br />
<span class="text">SVDFBDFBSFGSGSFBSN</span>
```

So texts are not the same lengths, but all buttons are the same width. I need some jQuery code to change font size by text length (then text longer - font smaller), but generated text needs to be 100px wide.

Comment: What have you already tried? [See this article on how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is example. `changes` array is for find if we oscillate around 100px. if yes, it breaks font changing function

http://jsfiddle.net/wasikuss/xbesnw93/

Answer (score 0):

you can get length of string with .length property.

so try this code.

```
$(".text").each(function(){
    var len= $(this).text().length
    var calculatedSize = //do calculate font size with length
    $(this).css("font-size", calculatedSize)
}
```

Comment: this is wrong .. you set the length for each element by the length of its text ?! why you want to do that .. he wants to set all the widths to the largest available width

Comment: i think it right. beause he said longer text, smaller font.